# Django rest framework : POST on many to many items

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a `TransactionType` model and I've implemented a viewset method to create transaction type as shown also below. Currently I can only post single credit_account or debit_account items as shown in this payload:

`{"name":"Repair and Maintenance","credit_account":16,"debit_account":38}`

I would to post multiple credit_accounts and debit_accounts such that my payload looks something like this:

`{"name":"Repair and Maintenance","credit_account":[16,4,5],"debit_account":[38,7]}`

Which is the efficient way of do this?

```
class TransactionType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    organization = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=False)  
    credit_account = models.ManyToManyField(Account,related_name='credit_account', verbose_name="Account to Credit")
    debit_account = models.ManyToManyField(Account,related_name='debit_account',verbose_name="Account to Debit")

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.name)
```

## viewset method

```
def create(self, request, format=None):

    name = request.data['name']

    try:

        trans_type_obj = TransactionType.objects.create(name=name,
                credit_account=Account.objects.get(id=request.data['credit_account'
                ]),
                debit_account=Account.objects.get(id=request.data['debit_account'
                ]), organization=get_auth(request))

        serializer = CreateTransactionTypeSerializer(trans_type_obj)
    except Exception, e:
        raise e

    return Response(data=serializer.data,
                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`ManyToManyField.add()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add) as below,

```
def create(self, request, format=None):
    name = request.data['name']

    try:

        trans_type_obj = TransactionType.objects.create(name=name, organization=get_auth(request))
        trans_type_obj.credit_account.add(*[credit_obj for credit_obj in Account.objects.filter(id__in=request.data['credit_account'])])
        trans_type_obj.debit_account.add(*[debit_obj for debit_obj in Account.objects.filter(id__in=request.data['debit_account'])])
        serializer = CreateTransactionTypeSerializer(trans_type_obj)
    except Exception, e:
        raise e

    return Response(data=serializer.data,
                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

**UPDATE-1**
as [@Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) said, it's also possible to do the same without list comperhension as

```
trans_type_obj.credit_account.add(*Account.objects.filter(id__in=request.data['credit_account']))
trans_type_obj.debit_account.add(*Account.objects.filter(id__in=request.data['debit_account']))
```

Comment: there is a problem with syntax when strating the for loop. `trans_type_obj.credit_account.add(*[for credit_obj in Account.objects.filter(id__in=request.data['credit_account'])])`
                                          ^

Comment: It works! I went to some extent to implement below  but your suggestion is better

Comment: Don't think you need the list comprehensions, `trans_type_obj.credit_account.add(*Account.objects.filter(id__in=request.data['credit_account']))` should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
def create(self, request,*args, **kwargs):

        name = request.data.pop('name')
        credits = request.data.pop('credit_account')
        debits = request.data.pop('debit_account')
        try:

            trans_type_obj = TransactionType.objects.create(name=name, organization=get_auth(request))
            for item in credits:
                trans_type_obj.credit_account.add(item)
            for item in debits:
                trans_type_obj.debit_account.add(item)

            serializer = TransactionTypeSerializer(trans_type_obj)
        except Exception as e:
            raise e

        return Response(data=serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create one serializer with following fields

```
class TransactionTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    credit_account = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Account.objects.all(), many=True)
    debit_account = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Account.objects.all(), many=True)

    class Meta:
         model = TransactionType
         fields = __all__
```

now in views

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
   serializer = TransactionTypeSerializer(data=request.data)
   serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
   serializer.save()
   return Response(serializer.data)
```